# Auto focus first time on loading page

Tags: reactjs

There is a input text in center in which I want to focus when the page loads, so I have used componentDidMount() and set the focus.

```
componentDidMount() {
 this.inputBar.focus();
}
.
.
<input type="text" ref={(element) => { this.inputBar = element; }}>
```

but it isn't working as a sidebar pops in as the page loads and shifts the focus from the center input.
I tried to use componentDidUpdate() but then it triggers the focus again and again when I close the sideBar. I only want to focus only at first time when I load the page.
I am new at coding, please suggest something that can be done here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you have to create ref , then in your lifecycle method use that ref, you have forgotten to use current when you are using ref in lifecycle method, your code will be like this:

```
class GroupDetail extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.inputRef = React.createRef();
}


componentDidMount(){
  this.ref.current.focus()
}

render(){
  return(
   <input type="text" ref={this.inputRef}/>
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: This is correct , but it isn't working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to focus a single Input then you can simply do

```
<input type="text" autofocus>
```

Comment: I have tried using 'autoFocus' and it works also but only when I disable the sidebar, with sidebar when page loads up the focus get shifted to the sidebar.  Here the sidebar has a default  behavior of popping up when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to focus an element when it mounts (initially renders) a simple use of the `autoFocus` attribute will do.

```
<input type="text" autoFocus />
```

Or if you want to do it with `componentDidMount` and to control focus dynamically you can go with the below snippet

```js
class App extends React.Component{
      componentDidMount(){
        this.nameInput.focus();
      }
      render() {
        return(
          <div>
            <input defaultValue="Won't focus"/>
            <input ref={(element) => { this.nameInput = element; }} defaultValue="will focus"/>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
        
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```